# How to transpose pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame using pandas and column labels that I need to edit to replace the original column labels.

```
|aa|0| bb|0| cc|xxxx| dd|axca | ee|zzzz |
|aa|0| bb|4| cc|yyyy| dd|axcab| ee|azxv |
```

and how i can convert it like table below,
thx before

```
|aa|bb|cc  |dd   |ee  |
|0 |0 |xxxx|axca |zzzz|
|0 |4 |yyyy|axcab|azxv|
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

Answer (score 0):

If need select unpair columns and set columns names by pair values by first row use:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1::2]
df1.columns = df.iloc[0, ::2].rename(None)
print (df1)
   aa  bb    cc     dd    ee
0   0   0  xxxx   axca  zzzz
1   0   4  yyyy  axcab  azxv
```